# difference between two lists greater than the difference in the number of elements in the two list

Tags: python, list

I have two lists (A, B)  of the files that have been processed. List A contains all the initial files, list B contains all the files that have been processed successfully (so the second list (B) is a subset of the first one).

*A contains 231453 items.*

*B contains 124769 items.*

I want to subtract them to see which of those files didn't get process. (C should contains 106684 items)

To do so I am using *set* :

```
newlist=[]
newlist2=[]
newlist3=[]
newlist=( set(A) - ( set(A) & set(B) ) )
newlist2=(set(A)^set(B))
newlist3=(set(A) - set(B))
print len(newlist)
print len(newlist2)
print len(newlist3)
```

The results are:

```
134173
161662
134173
```

> Why there are more items than the one expected?

Comment: We don't know enough about your lists and cannot assume they were generated properly. Have you checked that set(B) - set(A) is empty?

Comment: Ok, I finally understood the issue. List B has 27489 more files than expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have specified that A and B are lists. There is a possibility that there are duplicates in the list which are lost on converting to set.

> A set is a collection which is unordered and unindexed. In Python sets
>   are written with curly brackets.

For your case you could do

```
not_processed = filter(lambda x: x in A, B)
```

OR

```
not_processed = [x for x in A if x in B]
```

The above code will gice all the x values that are present in A if the X value is in B

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion works and gives the intersection between those two lists. The issue was related to the fact that list B had 27489 files.

Answer (score 0):

Your B contains some items that are not in A if B is subset of A then all three length should have been the same. The fact that your symmetric  different has higher length, your B contains certain items that are not in A